# HTC Desire HD & Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk

Does anyone have the HTC Desire HD setup in their SDK? if so could you please tell me what settings you picked to configure the AVD.

I have a website that renders properly on all android devices besides this one, so testing it is imperative !

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 configurations,

1. Android 2.2 API 8 skin WVGA800 240 density
2. Android 2.3.3 API 10 same skin and density

The only one that I use at the moment, is the 2nd because of the official gingerbread on DHD.

Comment: exactly similar to the device i had setup, but the website renders fine on this AVD but on the handset it seems to render incorrectly, same browser, same software, same everything the only thing i can think of is the DPI settings

Comment: uhm the device has a custom ROM? ( cyanogen, revolution HD, etc )

Answer (score 0):

The only setting which should affect the rendering of the site is the resolution. The Desire uses a 800x480 (WVGA) resolution screen.

Comment: Well i've experienced a few problems with this the Abstract LCD Density also effects the screen resolution.

I have setup the 800x480(WVGA) at a screen density of 240 (which renders the page @ around 320px wide XXX high) and also at 160 (which renders the page at 480x wide XXX high) and even with the density at 160 for the 480px wide device the CSS still doesn't render on the HTC DESIRE HD (but works on the HTC Desire)...

Comment: Perhaps check that they're using the same browser? As for sizing differences, I wouldn't be surprised if Android 'zooms in' on a higher DPI device.